# How can I influence which images facebook shows next to a link to my page?

Tags: php, html, facebook

I wrote a php-redirect script, that sends the user to different pages, depending on which device they used to access the page.

Now if I post a link to the page (www.ibeat.us/i.php) on facebook, facebook doesn't show any of my images I have on this page.
If I just add some "echo ..." lines, given the accessing machine is not running iOS, facebook writes those lines next to my link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the old `image_src`

```
<link rel="image_src" href="http://sample.com/my.jpg" />
```

Or the new Graph API `og:image` property

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://sample.com/my.jpg" />
```

If you go by new one, remember to use the Facebook and Open Graph namespaces

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:og="http://opengraphprotocol.org/schema/"
 xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
```

Comment: Thank you, that seems to work. Sometimes facebook is a little slow updating those pictures but it should be ok!