# Facebook thumbnail and php redirect

Tags: php, facebook, thumbnails

this question is a follow up to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4268825/how-can-i-influence-which-images-facebook-shows-next-to-a-link-to-my-page).

I have one server, with two domains associated with it (tactica.de and ibeat.us).
Now in my root folder I put an index.php that redirects users to the appropriate page, like this:

```
<?php
$url = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
if (!eregi("ibeat",$url)) {
    header('Location: http://tacticadev.wordpress.com/');
}
else {
    header('Location: http://tactica.de/ibeat/index.html');
}
?>
```

Now when I put the URL's "www.ibeat.us/index.php", "www.tactica.de/index.php" or even just "www.tactica.de" in a facebook-status the thumbnail-pictures show appropriately.
If I just add "www.ibeat.us" it doesn't even load a thumbnail, just shows the link without picture immediately!
Does anybody here have experiences with this, he may share?

Comment: Did you try to use a `.htaccess` redirect instead the PHP `header('Location')`?

Comment: I don't run an Apache server, I run nginx. I don't think its necessary to use .htaccess since the nginx configuration options should be able to do the same. Anyway, that is not the question I wanted to ask here. I mean the redirect works as its supposed to, and the thumbnails also work for the php file, like I wrote.

Comment: I only want to make sure Facebook is following the redirection, because dont seem so.

Comment: @Coquevas I thought they do, since giving the the link to the redirecting index.php file, facebook shows the different images, depending on what domain was given before the file. That is correct but also, just giving one domain without extension works. Just the other doesn't...

Comment: sorry, I missunderstood your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On `http://tactica.de/ibeat/index.html` the `<link>` tag is missplaced before the `<head>` tag. This malformed XHTML broke the facebook parser. Also notice that facebook cache the content of shared links for a few minutes.

Comment: Thank you for that advise, sadly it didn't change anything. Still the same result, even after waiting for some hours for fb to refresh.

Comment: Noy your `<link>` is after the `<head>` but must be *inside.* Also you can try this URL to debug the info that facebook is catching: http://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint/